# count data and categorical data in one generalized linear model. Is this possible?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, count-data

I have two variables measuring exposure.

1. Count data (number of exposures)
2. Categorical variable (exposed everyday, exposed a few times a week, exposed a few times a month, rarely exposed, and almost never exposed)

I want to perform a regression on these two in order to see how they associate.

My idea was to use a GLM with negative binomial distribution (the count data is a variable with an over-dispersed count outcome) with the count data as dependent variable and the categorical data as independent variable.
After analysis the pearsons R will be used to evaluate any linear relation between the two.

Is this statistically sound or should reconsider my approach?

Comment: Why not? What are your doubts?

Comment: Thank you for answering! I was doubting my approach since i have never performed such an analysis. The provided data we used during my education was always suitable for either logistic or linear regression. My current project on the other hand is more complex.

Comment: It's like ANOVA, itself a kind of linear regression, but in form of a GLM.